# Alamofire .POST response JSON nil using PHP

Tags: php, json, post, response, alamofire

How can I get JSON values back from my PHP script?

I get `nil` in my JSON response.

The `Alamofire.request` works.  (i.e. I receive JSON data at my PHP script.)

The PHP script works.  (i.e. I can process the input JSON and I generate a valid JSON string using `json_encode`.)

Here's the code...

Swift:

```
Alamofire
    .request(.POST, "http://www.myserver.com/from_swift.php", parameters: dicMyDictionary, encoding: ParameterEncoding.JSON)
    .responseJSON {
        (request, response, JSON, error) in
        println("request: \(request)")
        println("response: \(response)")
        println("JSON: \(JSON)")
        println("error: \(error)")
}
```

Println Results:

```
request: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7ff3b242de90> { URL: http://www.myserver/from_swift.php }

response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ff3b2776c40> { URL: http://www.myserver/from_swift.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Fri, 16 Jan 2015 12:02:24 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=200";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.4.36";
} })

JSON: nil

error: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7ff3b380db80 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    ... More code here ...
    echo json_encode($aryOfStrings);
?>
```

Solution:
I had an error in my PHP script.  As a result, the error message was being passed back in the response before the JSON string.  As a result, the `.responseJSON` correctly didn't recognize the data as JSON.

To help others, when you're getting `nil` in your data parameter from `.responseJSON`, troubleshoot by changing `.responseJSON` to `.responseString` to see if you get any results back in the data parameter.  For example, when I changed to `.responseString` I saw the following:

```
JSON: Optional("<br />\n<b>Strict Standards</b>:  mysqli::next_result(): There is no next result set. Please, call mysqli_more_results()/mysqli::more_results() to check whether to call this function/method in <b>/home/xxx/public_html/from_swift.php</b> on line <b>115</b><br />\n{\"books\":[\"the hunger games\",\"mockingjay\"]}")
```

Notice, the error message in front of the json string.  After I corrected the PHP script and changed back to `.responseJSON`, it worked...

Comment: Would be useful to print the JSON you are actually returning from your php script. You might want to hardcode a simple JSON response into your script to track down the issue. I am pretty certain, that's where the problem lies.